# How do I myself compute the median of the following pdf?

Tags: statistics

[image]
 I know how to calculate the median and the third quartile of a set of data but if it’s continuous I don’t know how to compute it

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397563/how-to-calculate-the-median-of-a-continuous-random-variable

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to integrate from $0$ to $z$ and see where $\int_0^z f(x) \, dx =0.5$. You are looking for the value of $X=z$. Here you have to do it stepwise.

$\underline{\text{Here   are  the  steps:}}$

**1)** First you to check if $\int_0^1 \frac34x^2 \, dx \geq 0.5$. If this is the case then the equation is $\int_0^z \frac34x^2 \, dx=0.5$. Calculate the integral and then solve the equation for $z$.

**2)** If $\int_0^1 \frac34x^2 \, dx<0.5$ then you have to use the following equation to evaluate the corresponing value of $X=z$:

$\int_0^1 \frac34x^2 \, dx+\int_{e}^{z} \frac1x \, dx  =0.5$

Comment: Thanks you anlot for your answer, But I think that the 1) and 2) here must be reversed

Comment: @RoyRizk Why do you think that?

Comment: Because if the integral of 3/4*x2 was sufficient to give me a  value more than 0.5 I’d be then sure that the median is located within this area. PS: how can I  write the symbol of integral and power and others.. with my pc

Comment: @RoyRizk Good catch. I´ve mixed up the equality signs. I´ve made an edit.  You can evaluate the codes if you click on the edit links. In my case it is this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2851711/edit) In general see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more formatting tips.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the median of a pdf $f:[a,b]$ is calculated by $\int_{a}^{m}{f(x) dx}=0.5$.

The integral of $3/4x^{2}$ from $0$ to $1$ is $1/4$.

So we need $\int_{e}^{m}\frac 1 x\, dx = 1/4$.

So we need $log_{e}(m)-log_{e}(e)=1/4$.

So $log(m)=1.25$ so $m=e^{1.25}$. Which is.....drumroll....3.49 :)

Comment: Made minor change in formatting of second integral for clarification.

Comment: Thank you, that is better.